# PHP Issue | Class Email Not found, Double Opt in form

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I recently came across this tutorial for creating a double opt in script. But it does not seem to be working.
Can someone check it out and see what's wrong with it?
Every time I try to use it, I get the error

> Class 'Email' not found in register.php at line 12

Here is the link to the article: http://tonygaitatzis.tumblr.com/post/66610863603/double-opt-in-email-registration

Here is the github link for the download: https://github.com/backupbrain/double-opt-in-registration-php

Answer (score 1):

In the register.php only emailregistration class is loaded.

But at line 12, you are trying to create instance of class email which is not loaded in this php file.

Load this class before using it in the code

```
require_once('classes/Email.class.php');
```

Comment: Ok, so i tried what you mentioned and i got the same error, only this time the error was Class Courier not found, so i decided to add require_once('classes/Courier.class.php'); And now i get this error syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/calofy/public_html/classes/Courier.class.php on line 85

Comment: There is a syntax error in courier class, at line no 80 there is no semicolon at the end of that instruction causing the error.

Comment: Well, it seems like i have a lot of errors, i added a semi colon but i am still getting errors, any chance you can have a look at the files and help me further, even though it is asking for a lot. @Nick

Comment: i checked couple of file and found that there is one more syntax error in emailregistration class at line 11 (semicolon is missing)..what i suggest you to check all these files for syntax validation, there are many online tools available which will validate the syntax

Comment: Hey mate, i took your suggestions and got it to work finally. Thanks so much for helping me constantly. Cheers!